# Linux 32 NASM How can i do this task ;( any tips?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have a problem with my exam and dont know how i can program this maybe someone has an idea.
I have to take random digits and letters from the comando row, overall there are 8 pieces ******** . The First digit or letter i have to multiply with 7 the second with 3 the third with 1 and then again from the beginning, the fourth digit or letter again with 7 this scheme up to the 8 numeral. Then after all i have to add up all digits and the last digit of the Result need to be output it.
i dont have an idea how i can do this maybe some one have an idea i think first of all i have to change the string into a integer and then? push on the stack? or what really dont know thx for your help

Comment: i have written something in asm code under this post pls watch there

Comment: That was deleted because you posted it as an answer, the idea is to press the edit button on your question and add the code in there.

Answer (score 0):

- try to create linux32 binary, that just cleanly exits (or even displays "hello world"). Verify it is really elf32 (and you are not building elf64, it's often default in modern 64b distros). If you have Win10, and you plan to use the ubuntu inside it, you are out of luck, it doesn't support 32b binaries, you will then need full common linux distro in some virtual machine. Use `strace ./<binary>` to see what system calls it is doing. Use debugger to single step over each instruction, see what values are in registers and check memory content (for example the instruction opcodes at entry point). I.e. verify your nasm + other tools are in place and works, and you are comfortable with them.
- modify it to "hello world" example, if it is not yet. Try to find tutorial which explains it enough, that you actually understand how it works.

From here on, after every following step always single-step over the code in debugger and reason about what the instructions are doing, and if they really do what you intended, without any unwanted side effects.

- Try programmatically change "e" to "E" (by a simple `mov` instruction, not by writing big E in the string definition). (to verify that you understand how string works, and also to put it into read-write memory, if you have original hello-world example with read-only definition).
- check some documentation/tutorials how command line arguments can be accessed, try to output it instead of hello world.

At this moment you should be skilled enough to access single letters of the input string.

- convert letter/digit from ASCII code to your encoding (I have a suspicion you have defined values for letters for the task, like `A` is `10`, etc., which is not compatible with ASCII, where `A` is `65`).
- multiply it by constant value, if you don't know yet how to have array of "weights".
- do that in some loop for all values
- create support array with multiplication weights (either 8 of them for each input char), or just the distinct ones + handle wrap-around.
- sum the results of multiplication into some intermediate result
- use `div 10` to extract last digit only as remainder of division
- convert the remainder into ASCII character, and store it into memory as string, to display it instead of hello world/etc. And display it.
- verify it four times in debugger, also for invalid inputs, etc.. fix all bugs.
- DONE.

> push on the stack?

Why? Does it make it more crisp or salty?

You know what your task is. It's actually quite neat task in terms that it really reads as calculation (with some other tasks it may be more difficult for beginners to see their calculation-nature, but this one is like naturally calculation-like, no subtlety or hiding). Focus on the task. If you need to multiply each letter, then just multiply it. If you need sum of the results, then just add summing. Etc.

Don't throw some code into the source just to try if it does help, assembly doesn't work like that, you have almost no chance to fix anything just by accident, by copy/pasting more and more code from Internet. That sort-of-works in high level languages, but never in assembly. Always focus what calculation you want, and write that in CPU instructions. For ideas what can be written in ASM, keep reading through instruction set reference guide (search for example for the 80386 limited list, which is enough for you task, but doesn't contain another hundreds of floating point/MMX/SSE instructions, which you can check later, after you have decent knowledge of the basic instructions). Check some simple tutorials to see how instructions are used to calculate desired result.

And yes, everything in computer is basically an calculation. You put the input values into, run the calculation over it, and output the results. It's just a bit more tricky, as the result is not numbers per-se, you can count as result of calculation also certain part of code executed, like "run this code calling OS API displaying a string". But nonetheless, think about it as about a deterministic calculation, going instruction by instruction. From one state you will get into next state. Find a formulae which leads from input state to the end state and write it in CPU instructions. Done.